# odoo 16 printing invoice by method

Tags: printing, invoice, odoo-16

i coded a method to post invoices like this:

`def print_invoice(self):

_logger.info('-#-#-#-#--#-#-#-in print_invoice')

line_array = []

for ar in self.ks_paketareale:

val = (0, None, {

'product_id': ar.ks_areal.id,

'name': ar.name,

'quantity': ar.ks_anzahl_behandlung,

'price_unit': ar.ks_areal.list_price,

'price_subtotal': ar.ks_areal.list_price * ar.ks_anzahl_behandlung,

})

line_array.append(val)

iid = self.env['account.move'].create({

'move_type': 'out_invoice',

'invoice_date': fields.Date.context_today(self),

'partner_id': self.partner_id.id,

#'currency_id': self.currency_id.id,

'amount_total': self.ks_rabattpreis,

'invoice_line_ids': line_array,

},

)

iid.action_post()

action = iid.action_invoice_print()

action.update({'close_on_report_download': True})`

creating the invoice works and the created invoice is posted.

but the call of iid.action_invoice_print() doesnt work. nothing happens.
i was excpecting that the download of the invoice starts because in the method 
_print_document in accout_move the method action_invoice_print is called.
whats going wrong? thx for any help

overriding action_post and action_print_invoice

Comment: At first sight, you forgot to return the action.
If you don't return the action, the function return None and the framework has no clue you're trying to call an action.

Answer (score 0):

Levizar’s comment was the crucial clue for solving my problem:

> You forgot to return the action. If you don't return the action, the function returns `None` and the framework has no clue you're trying to call an action.